# Does an n x n matrix A have a ker(A) = {0} no matter what even if A represents linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my textbook there is a theorem that says that because n x n matrices are inversible they have a bunch of proprieties. One of them that is the that Ker A = {0}.

However I was doing a practice problem where there was n x n matrix representing  a linear transformation and when I tried to solve Ax = 0 it didn't give me that Ker A = {0} and it was the correct answer.

Is there some sort of further conditon for nxn matrix to automatically have a Ker A  = {0}?

Comment: $0 \leq \dim(\ker(A)) \leq n$, depending on how many linearly independent columns there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because n x n matrices are inversible

and

> But doesn't the fact that A is n x n matrix implies that it is invertible?

Here's the problem: not all $n\times n$-matrices are invertible.

However: **if** an $n\times n$-matrix is invertible, then its kernel contains only the zero vector and vice versa; so those two properties are equivalent. This also means that if an $n\times n$-matrix is *not* invertible, the kernel will contain *more* than only the zero vector (and vice versa!).

Answer (score 2):

For a $n \times n$ matrix $A,$ $\text {Ker} (A) = \{0 \}$ if and only if $A$ is invertible.

Comment: But doesn't the fact that A is n x n matrix implies that it is invertible?

Comment: Nope. Take $n=2.$ Consider the $2 \times 2$ matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Is $A$ invertible?

Comment: Ah ok, I see now.